# How to hold mat tab for confirmation

Tags: angular, angular-material

My Requirement is when i click on mat tab it should show one warning saying are you sure. If User click on yes then only tab should change otherwise user will be on same tab. But when i click on one tab it will change the tab and then shows confirmation. i'm using ng-prime confirmation service.

```
<mat-tab-group >
    <mat-tab >
        <ng-template mat-tab-label let-value="value">
                <span (click)="onClick('abc')">TAB1</span>
        </ng-template>
    tab1
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab > <ng-template mat-tab-label>
            <span (click)="onClick('xyz')">TAB2</span>
    </ng-template>Tab 2
</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>




 onClick(label){
    if(label == "tab1"){

        this.confirmationService.confirm({
            key: "confirm-tab1",
            message: "Are you sure?",
            accept: () => { }


    }else if(label == "tab2"){
        this.confirmationService.confirm({
            key: "confirm-tab2",
            message: "Are you sure?",
            accept: () => { }
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve or what is your desired outcome?

Answer (score 0):

when you use `(click)="onClick('xyz')` you are sending `'xyz'` as a parameter rather than `'tab1'` or `'tab2'`, change it to `(click="onClick('tab2')` and it should work :)